# Difference between Cygwin and Command prompt when running an c++ application through command line

Tags: c++, command-line, cygwin

I have a C++ application that I am trying to run using the Windows command prompt by moving into the application directory and then call `appl.exe` with some arguments. The application gets launched(not yet closed), but the control returns to the command prompt.
Now when I do the same on Cygwin terminal, it waits for the application to exit before relinquishing the control.

I have tried to search for an answer but was not able to do so.

Can you please help me to understand the difference in behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminals in Windows like CMD and PowerShell launch applications in non-blocking mode (usually called the headless mode, if I'm not wrong. And it holds good for all executable files). There's nothing to bother until your application is running fine.

Cygwin, on the contrary, provides a Linux-like functionality, and thus follows the blocking nature of launching the application. That results in the Cygwin terminal to wait for the running application to quit to continue working.

Comment: To continue the previous comment: just add an & to put the app into the background. It will run as long as the starting bash is aive, i.e. as long as the mintty window is open.

Comment: @DougHenderson but that still has the drawback that the bash can be closed by mistake, which in turn will terminate the program.

Comment: See the doc for the nohup command. Or you might be able to use the start or cygstart command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, but is there a way to get cygwin like behavior on windows cmd prompt.

Comment: @rahulpoddaturi you can use `Start-Process -NoNewWindow myFile.exe`, but note that this command works only in PowerShell.

Comment: @DebarghaRoy I am able to use the reply to solve the issue. Thanks very much for your help.